# How to develop android apps with xamarin without hyper v and emulator

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-emulator, cross-platform, hyper-v

I am using windows 10 home and visual studio 2017. I want to develop android apps with xamarin. Hyper-V feature is not available on windows 10 home and I can not afford pro version, So emulator is not installing without hyper-v.

What should I do to develop android app?

Have anybody idea to deploy android app without using emulator and hyper-v?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to develop Xamarin app without using the emulators. But in that case you'll need to have an Android device to deploy your app on.

- Setup Android SDK Manager on your system. Although Xamarin includes a
  SDK Manager, you can download it from the following link. [Android SDK Manager download](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)
- Setup the ADB (Android Debug Bridge) on your system (install Google USB Drivers)
- Connect your Android device to the system after you enable USB Debugging(Developer options) on it. Once the device is connected it will give you a prompt to enable debugging. Tap yes and you'll see the option to build to your device as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: Clicking the 4th last icon as shown in the image will open standalone SDK Manager for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use any avaliable on windows android emulator. I like to use Bluestack (https://www.bluestacks.com), the steps for use it below:

1. Install **Bluestacks** emulator
2. **Launch emulator** and wait for load finished
   [image: Load]
   It's your wellcome screen, your application and apps from store will be here
3. Go to **settings** > **Preferences** and check **"Enable android debug bridge (ADB)"** + **"Enable Android input debugging"**

[image]
[image]

**One time Setup finished**

4. **"Open android adb command promt"** and type

> **adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555**

[image]

*If you have done everything good you will be connected to emulator and ready to debug your application*

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

### As of visual studio 2019, non-hyper v emulation has been stopped.

### Old Answer

I am very positive that at the time of VS installation the Visual studio emulators for Android are readily available for download and use, there you can find a good amount of android emulators also it provides you with Android SDK which again can be used to create Android emulators without using Hyper-V

The below link contains all you need to know about Visual studio emulators including on how to install :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228279.aspx

Hope this Answers your question.
Goodluck!

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 seems to have stopped non Hyper-V emulation