# Android emulator starts but app doesn't show up

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator

I'm new to Xamarin, I created a blank app just to try it out

I have Windows Home so I can only have Android Studio's emulator. The emulator works fine when I either launch it from avd manager or visual studio, but from the latter my project just won't load.

From xamarin broker logs I get this error :

System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ServerPacketListener: Error: 0: Server - An error occurred while listening and dispatching packets
System.Net.Mqtt.MqttException: The keep alive tolerance of 00:00:45 seconds has been exceeded and no packet has been received from client

[[ From the avd manager when I launch the emulator I get this error "Telnet connection failed", idk what this means bc I can still access the internet through the emulator ]] EDIT : I activated telnet so i dont get this anymore, still not working tho

I tried to reinstall everything (sdk + vs)
I found several solutions which involve launching the emulator from the avd manager then deploy the solution from vs, but that seems to be possible only with visual studio emulator
I tried this [App not run in visual studio emulator for android in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560853/app-not-run-in-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-visual-studio-2015#32564067) but it uses a visual studio emulator which i can't have (it needs windows pro or enterprise for hyperV)

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need hyperV to make this work. You can try this other way-install Android studio and build an app to the emulator from there. If successful, go back to Visual studio and select the Android Studio emulator from your visual studio emulator list This time and try to build.

Comment: Problem is I cannot enable HyperV which is only available on windows enteprise or pro (i have windows home) but I do have HAXM enabled which should work. I'll try android studio anyway

Comment: Try android studio, but the chances are you can’t use that computer unless you have VS 2017 somehow https://stackoverflow.com/q/47570489/11104068

Comment: Please use `adb devices` to verify that if the Android SDK can connect to your emulator, there are detailed steps in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows).

Comment: It works, I think the problem is that visual studio cannot connect to the device. Anyway I have resolved the issue by creating a new user in  Windows, cannot say why it wouldn't work on the first session..