# Xamarin initial setup not working because of Hyper-V issues

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am on a Windows 10 Home PC with Intel i7. I was having trouble setting up my first xamarin project and would really appreciate help. So I keep getting this error when trying to run a google pixel emulator (the default one)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbaxq.png)

So I went to turn windows features on and off and enabled the Windows Hypervision Platform. Trouble is, I couldn't find the Hyper-V folder itself. So I did some googling and found this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/34a2c6b8-0b89-434d-8dfe-0f6bd2a4b976/cant-find-hyperv-on-windows-features

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfC5J.png)

Does this mean that I cannot develop Xamarin because I have windows 10 home? Really? That's a massive pain in the ass if true. If not true, what can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to develop android apps with xamarin without hyper v and emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570489/how-to-develop-android-apps-with-xamarin-without-hyper-v-and-emulator)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v Says the requirements are Pro and Enterprise. However, some people say differently https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/29175/installation-of-hyper-v-on-windows-10-home.html

Comment: Personally I find it more convenient to debug and develop on an actual device, the pros outweigh the cons for me (in some situations)

Comment: you can develop Xamarin, you just can't run the emulator.  Look at alternate emulators like Genymotion, or test using a real Android device